# Billboard.js: $$.generatePoint is not a function

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, billboard.js

I'm trying to use `billboard.js` as a simple alternative to `d3.js` for displaying some line graphs. Unfortunately, I can't seem to get it working in my own repository, nor can I get it working in a vanilla Vue project.

**Can anyone tell me if something special is required to get `billboard.js` up and running in combination with Vue?**

My App.vue:

```html
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <img alt="Vue logo" src="./assets/logo.png">
    <div id="chart">
  </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator';
import { bb } from 'billboard.js';

@Component
export default class App extends Vue {
  mounted() {
    console.log(this);
    console.log(bb);
    bb.generate({
      bindto: '#chart',
      data: {
        columns: [
          ['data1', 30, 200, 100, 170, 150, 250],
        ],
        types: {
          data1: 'line',
          data2: 'area-spline',
        },
        colors: {
          data1: 'red',
          data2: 'green',
        },
      },
    });
  }
}
</script>
```

And the error code I get from my devtools:

```
vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:619 [Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: $$.generatePoint is not a function"

found in

---> <App> at src/App.vue
       <Root>
```

For what it's worth, I am using the following npm versions for this project:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "billboard.js": "^2.0.3",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "vue": "^2.6.11",
    "vue-class-component": "^7.2.3",
    "vue-property-decorator": "^8.4.2"
  },
```

I've created [a small repository](https://github.com/TemporaryStackOverflowAccount/VuejsAndBillboardjs/tree/master/testbillboard) with the minimum code required to reproduce this issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the [docs](https://github.com/naver/billboard.js/wiki/CHANGELOG-v2#modularization-by-its-functionality), the correct usage for the ESM build is:

```js
// BEFORE:
//import { bb } from 'billboard.js';

// AFTER:
import bb, { line, areaSpline } from 'billboard.js';


export default {
  mounted() {
    bb.generate({
      //...
      data: {
        types: {
          // BEFORE:
          //data1: 'line',
          //data2: 'area-spline',

          // AFTER:
          data1: line(),
          data2: areaSpline(),
        },
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Also, if you intend to have multiple instances of this chart component on a page, you should pass unique references to the chart's parent element via a [`ref`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref):

```html
<template>
  <!-- BEFORE: -->
  <!-- <div id="chart" /> -->

  <!-- AFTER: -->
  <div ref="chart" />
</template>

<script>
export default {
  async mounted() {
    // wait til next tick for `ref` to be available below
    await this.$nextTick();

    bb.generate({
      //...
      bindto: this.$refs.chart,
    });
  }
}
</script>
```

[GitHub PR with fixes](https://github.com/TemporaryStackOverflowAccount/VuejsAndBillboardjs/pull/1/commits/442490d3d734600f29cc55ef9281e03ffbae50d9)